# @ApplicationException and server logging

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I have a webservice which creates an account, but can throw an exception.
   Account createAccount() throws AccountException.

AccountException is annotated with @AppliationException.

The client receives this AccountException and handles this correct.

But in server log (jboss7) I always see the full stacktrace for my application.

Is there any way to shrink this logging (e.g to exception.getMessage()) in server's logging WITHOUT configuring the server?

If there is only a solution by configuring the server I also interessted in this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following 
https://community.jboss.org/message/622614

The problem is: that the default formatter has a %E (implicit) included -> Full stacktrace.

If I define my own pattern-formatter and don't specify a %E, so the full stacktrace is skipped.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
  <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
    <formatter>
    <!--
      <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
    -->
      <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%n"/>
    </formatter>
  </console-handler>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to configure logging of the server to hide that exception.

Comment: Thanks. I try this until I found a better solution.